How do you stop Prettier in VS code splitting CSS Selectors into multiple lines?
I want the code to look like this:
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5 {
  font-weight: 400 !important;
}

But Prettier - Code Formatter is breaking each selector into individual lines:
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5 {
  font-weight: 400 !important;
}

CSS Selectors being split into multiple lines

I don't think it lets you to do that. Prettier is opinionated and I believe all of its configurable options are documented here.
